# Bash merge variable

Tags: bash, sed, merge

I'm trying to get status information about VPN connections.
It's almost done, except for the part to return the actual PH2 name:

#### Step 1

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDIFS=$IFS
export IFS=`/bin/echo -ne " \t\n"`
VPN="VPN-AAA-BBB-1"
ph2table=$(snmpwalk 192.168.1.1 -c public -v2c fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib | sed "s/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB:://" | sed "s/STRING: //" | grep $VPN)
```

`$ph2table` now contains:

```
fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name.71 = VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-0.1
fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name.72 = VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-0.2
fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name.73 = VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-0.3
fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name.74 = VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-0.4
fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name.75 = VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-1.5
fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name.76 = VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-1.6
fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name.77 = VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-1.7
fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name.78 = VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-1.8
fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name.79 = VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-2.9
fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name.80 = VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-3.10
```

#### Step 2

```
clean=$(echo $ph2table | sed 's/fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name/fgVpnTunEntStatus/' | sed 's/=.*//')
```

`$clean` now contains:

```
fgVpnTunEntStatus.71
fgVpnTunEntStatus.72
fgVpnTunEntStatus.73
fgVpnTunEntStatus.74
fgVpnTunEntStatus.75
fgVpnTunEntStatus.76
fgVpnTunEntStatus.77
fgVpnTunEntStatus.78
fgVpnTunEntStatus.79
fgVpnTunEntStatus.80
```

#### Step 3

```
export IFS=$OLDIFS

for i in "$clean" ; do snmpget 192.168.1.1 -c public -v2c $i -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib ; done | sed "s/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB::fgVpnTunEntStatus.//" | sed 's/= INTEGER: //'
```

This will return:

```
71 up(2)
72 down(1)
73 up(2)
74 up(2)
75 up(2)
76 up(2)
77 up(2)
78 up(2)
79 up(2)
80 up(2)
```

---

What I'm trying to get as final output is:

```
VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-0.1 71 up(2)
VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-0.2 72 down(1)
VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-0.3 73 up(2)
VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-0.4 74 up(2)
VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-1.5 75 up(2)
VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-1.6 76 up(2)
VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-1.7 77 up(2)
VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-1.8 78 up(2)
VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-2.9 79 up(2)
VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-3.10 80 up(2)
```

I can't seem to find a way to merge things together. Any idea's about this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing stuff in variables is not how it's usually done by veteran shell script programmers.  Just keep everything in a pipeline.

This is really simple, but I want to explain why I changed some things, so an annotated version is included below.

```
#!/bin/bash

VPN="VPN-AAA-BBB-1"

snmpwalk 192.168.1.1 -c public -v2c fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name \
    -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib |
sed -e 's/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB:://' -e 's/STRING: //' -e "/$VPN/!d" |
while read i _ id; do
    snmpget 192.168.1.1 -c public -v2c "$i" \
        -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib |
    sed -e 's/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB::fgVpnTunEntStatus.//' -e 's/= INTEGER: //' \
        -e "s/^/$id /"
done
```

(There isn't anything Bash-specific here, so you could change the shebang to `#!/bin/sh` actually.  This is hardly important here, but if you need to run this on systems where Bash is too large or too slow or unavailable, the option to use Dash instead is perhaps attractive.)

The annotated version is a bit longwinded and has a pesky vertical scroll bar, but the comments explain what I changed and why.

```
#!/bin/bash
#OLDIFS=$IFS
#export IFS=`/bin/echo -ne " \t\n"`
# No need to export (you don't want or need this in subprocesses)
# No need to echo (bash has adequate internal facilities for representing strings)
# IFS=$' \t\n'
# Commented out because we do the required parsing in sed instead

VPN="VPN-AAA-BBB-1"

#ph2table=$(snmpwalk 192.168.1.1 -c public -v2c fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name \
#-m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib |
#sed "s/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB:://" | sed "s/STRING: //" | grep $VPN)
# No need to use multiple processes; sed can do everything in one go
# No need for a variable -- feed this into a pipeline
snmpwalk 192.168.1.1 -c public -v2c fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name \
    -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib |
sed -e 's/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB:://' -e 's/STRING: //' -e "/$VPN/!d" |

# The following could be added to replace "clean" but we take a different approach
#    -e 's/fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name/fgVpnTunEntStatus/' -e 's/=.*//' |

#clean=$(echo $ph2table | sed 's/fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name/fgVpnTunEntStatus/' |
#sed 's/=.*//')|
# No need for a variable
# $ph2table absolutely needs to be quoted here -- "$ph2table"
# but we don't want to do this -- instead, keep this in the output

#export IFS=$OLDIFS
# No longer necessary -- see above

#for i in "$clean" ; do
# Instead of a for loop over a variable, do a while loop over output lines from pipe
# Split into i, equals sign (in $_, which we ignore), and id
while read i _ id; do

    #snmpget 192.168.1.1 -c public -v2c $i \
    #-m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib ; done |
    # Definitely need to quote "$i"

    snmpget 192.168.1.1 -c public -v2c "$i" \
        -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib |

    #sed "s/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB::fgVpnTunEntStatus.//" |
    # sed 's/= INTEGER: //'
    # Again, use a single sed invocation
    # Factor this inside the while loop, and add the id to the output
    sed -e 's/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB::fgVpnTunEntStatus.//' \
        -e 's/= INTEGER: //' \
        -e "s/^/$id /"

done
```

Comment: Thank you. As you have seen I'm not that good at bash, or scripting at all for that matter ;-). How can I use the final output later on in my script?
F.e: 
if  up > exit 0
if down > exit 2

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. Your sample contains both up and down lines; should that be success or failure?

Comment: Here's my output:
VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-1.1 down(1)
VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-1.2 up(2)
VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-1.3 up(3)

I'd like to use that info to create an exit:

if [[ output == *"down*" ]] ; then
 echo output
 exit 2
else
 echo output
 exit 0
fi

Comment: Ah, easy enough with var=$( <your script> )
Thank you for your explanation, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be simplest to take a step back and do this on the fly:

```
while read ph; do
  # clean is only a single cleaned entry now
  clean=$(echo "$ph" | sed 's/fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name/fgVpnTunEntStatus/;s/ =.*//')

  # status for that one entry
  status=$(snmpget 192.168.1.1 -c public -v2c "$clean" -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib | sed 's/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB::fgVpnTunEntStatus.//; s/= INTEGER: //')

  # isolate VPN-AAA-BBB-1-P2-x.y part
  cur=$(echo "$ph" | sed 's/.* = //')

  # print the stuff we want.
  echo "$cur $status"

# instead of feeding "$phtable2" to the loop, it would also be possible to
# pipe the output of the command that was put there directly through the loop,
# as in command | while read ph; do ... done
done <<< "$phtable2"
```

The code is necessarily untested because I don't have your SNMP setup, but I hope the general idea becomes clear from it.

I would also take a look at the documentation of the snmp tools and see if there isn't a more direct way of isolating the values of the variables than piping it all through sed. That could become a problem if the tools are updated and their output format changes slightly.

Answer (score 0):

If the lines will definitely match up, you can combine them with [paste(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/paste).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but something like this should work:

```
VPN="VPN-AAA-BBB-1" && while read -ra myarr; do
snmp=$(snmpget 192.168.1.1 -c public -v2c "${myarr[0]}" -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib ; done | sed "s/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB::fgVpnTunEntStatus.//" | sed 's/= INTEGER: //')
echo "${myarr[0]} ${snmp}"
done < <(snmpwalk 192.168.1.1 -c public -v2c fgVpnTunEntPhase2Name -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib | sed "s/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB:://" | sed "s/STRING: //" | grep "${VPN}")
```

This steers clear of playing around with the IFS, if your code exits while the IFS is set (not trapping errors) you could have unpredictable behavior like you said.